# How to parse text into sentences

Tags: java, text-parsing

I'm trying to break up a paragraph into sentences. Here is my code so far:

```
import java.util.*;

public class StringSplit {
 public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
     String testString = "The outcome of the negotiations is vital, because the current tax levels signed into law by President George W. Bush expire on Dec. 31. Unless Congress acts, tax rates on virtually all Americans who pay income taxes will rise on Jan. 1. That could affect economic growth and even holiday sales.";
     String[] sentences = testString.split("[\\.\\!\\?]");
     for (int i=0;i<sentences.length;i++){  
         System.out.println(i);
      System.out.println(sentences[i]);  
     }  
 }
}
```

Two problems were found:

1. The code splits anytime it comes to a period (".") symbol, even when it's actually one sentence.  How do I prevent this?
2. Each sentence that is split starts with a space. How do I delete the redundant space?

Answer (score 14):

The problem you mentioned is a NLP (Natural Language Processing) problem. It is fine to write a crude rule engine but it might not scale up to support full english text.

To have a deeper insight and a java library check out this link http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml , http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/index.jsp and similar question for `ruby` language [How do you parse a paragraph of text into sentences? (perferrably in Ruby)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860809/how-do-you-parse-a-paragraph-of-text-into-sentences-perferrably-in-ruby)

for example :
The text -

> The outcome of the negotiations is
>   vital, because the current tax levels
>   signed into law by President George W.
>   Bush expire on Dec. 31. Unless
>   Congress acts, tax rates on virtually
>   all Americans who pay income taxes
>   will rise on Jan. 1. That could affect
>   economic growth and even holiday
>   sales.

after tagging becomes :

> The/DT outcome/NN of/IN the/DT
>   negotiations/NNS is/VBZ vital/JJ ,/,
>   because/IN the/DT current/JJ tax/NN
>   levels/NNS signed/VBN into/IN law/NN
>   by/IN President/NNP George/NNP W./NNP
>   Bush/NNP expire/VBP on/RP Dec./NNP
>   31/CD ./. Unless/IN Congress/NNP
>   acts/VBZ ,/, tax/NN rates/NNS on/IN
>   virtually/RB all/RB Americans/NNPS
>   who/WP pay/VBP income/NN taxes/NNS
>   will/MD rise/VB on/IN Jan./NNP 1/CD
>   ./. That/DT could/MD affect/VB
>   economic/JJ growth/NN and/CC even/RB
>   holiday/NN sales/NNS ./. Parse

Check how it has distinguished the full stop (.) and the period after Dec. 31 ...

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use the `java.text.BreakIterator` class for parsing sentences. For example:

```java
BreakIterator border = BreakIterator.getSentenceInstance(Locale.US);
border.setText(text);
int start = border.first();
//iterate, creating sentences out of all the Strings between the given boundaries
for (int end = border.next(); end != BreakIterator.DONE; start = end, end = border.next()) {
    System.out.println(text.substring(start,end));
}
```

Comment: `BreakIterator` is a good idea, but it suffers from many of these same types of problems.  See this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17159513/split-paragraph-into-sentences-with-titles-and-numbers

Answer (score 2):

The first one is a pretty hard problem to do properly, since you'd have to implement sentence detection. I suggest you don't do that, and just separate sentences with two blank lines after a punctuation mark. For example:

```
"The outcome of the negotiations is vital, because the current tax levels signed into law by President George W. Bush expire on Dec. 31.  Unless Congress acts, tax rates on virtually all Americans who pay income taxes will rise on Jan. 1.  That could affect economic growth and even holiday sales."
```

The second one can be solved using [String.trim()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29).

Example:

```
String one = "   and now...    ";
String two = one.trim();
System.out.println(two);          // output: "and now..."
```

Comment: The problem with your first solution is that in the last decade or so there has been a shift from inserting two spaces between sentences to inserting only one.  For writing done with this newer style, your solution won't work.  :(

Answer (score 0):

[Trim](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) it...

Answer (score 0):

Given the current input format, it will be difficult to split into sentences. You have to impose some rule additional rule to identify the end of a sentence, in addition to the period. For instance, this rule could be "a sentence should end with a period(.) and two spaces". (This is how the UNIX tool `grep` identifies sentences.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Class `SentenceSplitter` provided by this open source library [here](http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/page/software_view/LBJ).

```
SentenceSplitter sp = new SentenceSplitter("filename");
String str = null;
while((str = sp.next().toString()) != null)
{
    //Your code here.
}
```

Comment: Nothing to download at this URL.  It returns "You don't have permission to access /page/download_view/ on this server."

Answer (score -1):

first Trim() Your String... and use this link

http://www.java-examples.com/java-string-split-example   &http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0438.html

and you can also use StringBuffer Class... just use this link i hope it will help you