# Split text into sentence even Mr. Mrs. exists in a text

Tags: c#, split

I have a problem, I want split a text into sentence using fullstop (.)

For instance:

**Mr. Bean** is a British comedy television series of 14 half-hour episodes starring Rowan Atkinson as the title character. Different episodes were written by Atkinson, Robin Driscoll, Richard Curtis and one by Ben Elton.

If I split the above text, I got 3 sentences like,

**1.** Mr.

**2.** Bean is a British comedy television series of 14 half-hour episodes starring Rowan Atkinson as the title character. Different episodes were written by Atkinson, Robin Driscoll, Richard Curtis and one by Ben Elton.

**3.** Different episodes were written by Atkinson, Robin Driscoll, Richard Curtis and one by Ben Elton.

---

I want to include **Mr.** in the second sentence as the text should split into two sentence not to three.

**1. Mr. Bean** is a British comedy television series of 14 half-hour episodes starring Rowan Atkinson as the title character. Different episodes were written by Atkinson, Robin Driscoll, Richard Curtis and one by Ben Elton.

**2.** Different episodes were written by Atkinson, Robin Driscoll, Richard Curtis and one by Ben Elton.

Kindly help me. I appreciate the instant feedback from the community.

Thanks.

Comment: What language are you wishing to achieve this in?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860809/how-do-you-parse-a-paragraph-of-text-into-sentences-perferrably-in-ruby

Comment: @diagonalbatman I am using C#.NET

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are looking for a way to avoid splitting sentences after an abbreviation (like `a.m.`), that's a difficult natural language problem.

If you just want to split sentences without worrying about Mr. or Mrs. (and have a character that won't likely show up in the text, like `*`), here's a simple way:

1. replace all instances of `Mr.` and `Mrs.` with `Mr*` and `Mrs*`
2. split text on `.`
3. in the resulting array, replace all instances of `Mr*` and `Mrs*` with `Mr.` and `Mrs.`

Here's a version that uses NUL as a sentinel character, as it's pretty much impossible for it to show up in text unintentionally:

```
static IEnumerable<string> Splitter(string sentences)
{
    char sentinel = '\0';
    return sentences.Replace("Mr.", "Mr" + sentinel)
        .Replace("Mrs.", "Mrs" + sentinel)
        .Split(new[] { ". " }, StringSplitOptions.None)
        .Select(s => s.Replace("Mr" + sentinel, "Mr.")
                        .Replace("Mrs" + sentinel, "Mrs."));
}
```

If you're the paranoid sort of person who thinks any particular character is liable to show up in your text, feel free to use a GUID for the sentinel.

Comment: The source text "Mr. Mr* Bean" would then be turned into "Mr. Mr. Bean"

Comment: @Gareth: I told the OP to choose a character that's not likely to show up in his text, like `*`. If `Mr*` is likely to show up in his text, he *shouldn't* use `*` as the character!

Comment: @Gabe - By choosing a less obvious character you're just making sure the problem doesn't show up until you're totally not expecting it

Comment: @Gareth: Just choose NUL as the character if you're worried about it. Or are you worried that a NUL is going to appear amidst some random English sentences?

Answer (score 3):

The only way (I can think of right now) to do this, is to add intelligence to the split function. When to use the . as delimiter and when not.

You can do this like:

1. Replace all occurences of `<dot>` by `<dot><dot>`.
2. Replace all Mr. (and other entries in the dictionary) by `Mr<dot>`.
3. Split the text using the remaining dots.
4. Replace all `Mr<dot>` (and other...) by Mr. .
5. Replace all occurences of `<dot><dot>` by `<dot>`.

Of course you can use another escape character/string.

You can keep a dictionary of translations. Preferably in a file so you can use a different dictionary for different languages.

Comment: This still has an edge case similar to that found in Gabe's answer.  The edge case only applies when you have a delimiter directly to the right of a Mr./Mrs.  For example, `Mr<dot><dot>Text`, which will become `Mr[split]<dot>Text` instead of `Mr<dot>[split]Text`.  So, the error window is narrower, but not gone.  Of course, if your splitter function (with `<dot><dot>` as a delimiter) always splits `<dot><dot><dot>` as `<dot>[split]` instead of `[split]<dot>`, this issue would be resolved.  This could be done using `Regex.Split`...but with `Regex.Split` none of this fanciness is necessary :)

Answer (score 1):

```
static IEnumerable<string> Splitter(string sentences)
{
    foreach (string s in 
        Regex.Split(sentences, "(?<!((mr)|(mrs)))\\.", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)) yield return s.Trim() + ".";
    }
}
```

A simple regex-based answer using negative look-behind.

Comment: but what happend if you split the following sentence. ["New Zealand’s second largest city has had to be closed immediately due to the 6.3 magnitude earthquake on February 22, 2011."]. I would break it into two sentences if I use your method to split the text. you effort is appreciable.

Comment: @Rais: Every method posted suffers from that problem.  As Gabe mentioned, that is a difficult natural language problem.  It is a *very* hard problem.  A simple and mostly reasonable approach would be to change the regex to split on `\\.\\s` instead of `\\.` , but it wouldn't be 100% accurate.