# Ruby, Split Text Into Sentences

Tags: ruby, regex

Following a tutorial in a book, using the following code to split text into sentences,

```
def sentences
    gsub(/\n|\r/, ' ').split(/\.\s*/)
end
```

It works, but if theres a newline which began without a period preceding it, for example,

```
Hello. two line sentence
and heres the new line
```

theres a "\t" placed at the beginning of each sentence.  So if i called the method on the above sentence i would get

```
["Hello." "two line sentence /tand heres the new line"]
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I think it's not clear what you are asking. What exactly you want to do and what is getting wrong?

Comment: So the method should split text into sentences based on a period followed by a whitespace.

Comment: So calling .sentences on the above lines should result in ["Hello", "two line sentence and heres the new line"] but i am getting a /t when theres a new line.

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Ruby/String/SplittingTextintoSentences.htm  basically this.

Comment: How about `gsub(/(\n|\r\n)/,' ').split(/\.\s*/)`?

Comment: I think that the origin of the problem is probably that the tab character was already here. You can avoid the problem using `gsub(/\s+/, ' ')` that is more radical.

Answer (score 3):

Splitting text into sentences is best achieved using [Stanford CoreNLP](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/). In the example method provided in the question, any acronyms or name prefixes such as "Mr." would also be split.

The [stanford-core-nlp](https://github.com/louismullie/stanford-core-nlp) ruby gem provides the ruby interface. See the instructions for [installing the gem and Stanford CoreNLP in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41338411/4852737), then you could write some code like this:

```
require "stanford-core-nlp"

StanfordCoreNLP.use :english
StanfordCoreNLP.model_files = {}
StanfordCoreNLP.default_jars = [
  'joda-time.jar',
  'xom.jar',
  'stanford-corenlp-3.5.0.jar',
  'stanford-corenlp-3.5.0-models.jar',
  'jollyday.jar',
  'bridge.jar'
]

pipeline =  StanfordCoreNLP.load(:tokenize, :ssplit)

text = 'Hello. two line sentence
and heres the new line'
text = StanfordCoreNLP::Annotation.new(text)
pipeline.annotate(text)
text.get(:sentences).each{|s| puts "sentence: " + s.to_s}

#output:
#sentence: Hello.
#sentence: two line sentence
#and heres the new line
```